# What is the max size of a scene in Blender?

Tags: 3d-view, import, scene

I created a landscape full size in Autodesk Inventor from shapes I traced using AutoCAD.  I made it from a chart of Charleston Harbor that was created in 1861.  It is about 8 x 10 nautical miles square.  I made extruded shapes and brought the file into 3DS Max so that I could export an FBX file that I brought into Blender.  The shapes seem to have come in fine, but they drift in and out of the visible space as I rotate the view.  It appears that I have exceeded the size of mesh that I can use. [image]

Can you tell me what the limits are for importing meshes into Blender?[image]

How would you approach this?

I intend to use in my Blender class it to get my students to recreate the "Race to Freedom" of a steamship that was commandeered by Robert Smalls a slave and turned over to the Union Blockade of Ft. Sumter in 1862.

Can you place an image into Blender that is that large?  I mean a full scale chart of Charleston Harbor.

Is it possible to scale a reference image that big and accurately inside Blender?

Comment: AFAIK there is no limit (only your hardware) , for the view limit you are facing there is an clipping option 3D_view->right side panel ->view->clipping_end change this value

Comment: This one is inspiring on how to import cities: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R1ROxTnD3E0, the area you're trying to cover is way too large to be more than cubes with roofs (IMHO).

Comment: somehow related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23787/need-advice-for-creating-a-simple-scene-with-very-large-dimensions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set clipping limits for 3D view and for camera:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please don't highlight the images like that, in the future - it's kinda annoying to lot at... Please use just an outline, instead of a filled rectangular-ish shape

Comment: Clipping limits is exactly what I needed.  Thanks.  As far as the highlights, they don't bother me but I don't think they were needed.  The screen captures said it all.

Comment: I've used this several times in class now.  Thanks again!

Comment: Does the clipping apply to the 3D view window even if there is no camera, or does it only apply to a camera?

Comment: @uhoh it does indeed apply to 3D view even if a camera is absent.  It is also worth noting that having too small a Start value relative to your model size will cause drawing issues - for instance if your part is 10,000 units wide and your Start value is 0.001 it will not display properly.