# Move multiple objects without parenting?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I create an scene with 10.000 objects.
Now showing an big problem.

I have to move the scene to an settled point.
As example:
choose 1 of the 10.000 objects as reference object. This object located at x=0, y=0, z=0.
Now i need the reference object at (example) x=250.000,00, y=500.000,00 z=399,00

tested already parenting the 9.999 objects with the reference object. Moving to new position works but my scene become glitchy through this process.

Lookin for an way to get the objects to new location without parenting.
Is this possible?

hope, somebody can help me.

Comment: I don't think parenting is the problem. It might add some overhead, but your main problem is moving a lot of objects at once. You can just select multiple objects and move them without parenting, but likely this will result with a similar lag.

Answer (score 1):

You could just select all *"A"*, *"G"* to move and type in the desired ofset for which you want to move it in the *Move* pop-up:

[image]

It may get laggy as well. One way around would be to hide part of the scene and move it separately.

Comment: Same problem unfortunaly, moving works but the models will be glitchy .. very strange. If i select all objects and move them via "hand" a few hundret meter everything is fine and not glitchy. But i cant move the whole scene via hand 250.000 meter. Dont know, whats the problem at this case :/

Comment: What exactly do you mean with models being glitchy? Your Blender gets slow? If that's the case, hiding / disabling some objects in the objects list and moving few at a time doesn't solve the problem?

Comment: no, blender will get not slow. The objects flickers after moving. I guess the problem is the high position value of x and y .. I have tried an new scene with only 1 cube and move it to 250000m, 150000m and its flickers too .. I guess blender cant handle these positions ..

Comment: Got it, check this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26955/what-is-the-max-size-of-a-scene-in-blender