# Black areas in final render

Tags: rendering

New to Blender, new to 3D modelling with SfM. I have a 3D model of a wreck area generated from stills with Agisoft, and then imported into Blender. Upon rendering I get black areas, see screen dump. In the viewport everything looks good.

Is this a problem with the imported 3D-model, or something I have missed when rendering?

Follow-up question; Is it fixable in Blender?

I'm on Windows, Blender 2.75a.

Regards,

Pär

[image: Screen dump showing black areas after render.]

[image: Screen dump showing no black areas before render]

Comment: Does this help? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/cause-of-black-artifacts-in-render

Comment: I tried the Remove Doubles operator, no change. It said up in the top of Blender zero faces removed.

Comment: Are you able to provide the file (or a cut down version of the file) for us to look at? Here is a good place to upload it if you are: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It does look like Z-Fighting. Either by duplicated geometry or by issues with precision created by the clipping distances: see this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21647/weird-shading-effects-when-rendering-at-long-distance Try to keep the clip max and min distances so that they cover your scene but not more than that.

Comment: I tried the min/max clipping at several different values, it didn't help, even if it sure looks like the Z-Fighting.  Here is a cutout of the blenderfile:[<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=556" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/556/)   (Which also shows my next question, what am I doing wrong in the cutout? As you can see there are lots of datapoints left.)

Comment: Any further comments? @RayMairlot

Comment: @PärE I was not able to see the black areas when I rendered the model so it's hard to say what the problem could be I'm afraid.

Comment: OK, so if it renders OK on your side it looks like I'm doing something wrong on my side. Could you maybe take a screen shot of your settings? Or if you tell me which settings are relevant I'll make a screen shot of my settings and post. @RayMairlot