# Blender Cycles Render errors when dealing with a scene with very large dimensions

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

I am making a to scale representation of our solar system. I made an 864,340 mile diameter sun with emission and placed a 7,917.6 mile diameter earth 92.96 million miles away. It has 3 layers, the ground, the clouds, and the atmosphere.

When the earth is placed at 0 ,0 ,0. Has all layers.

[image]

When the earth is placed at 0, 0, 92.96 million miles and lit by the massive sun.

[image]

When the clouds is placed around it at 0, 0, 92.96 million miles.

[image]

When the atmosphere is placed around it at 0, 0, 92.96 million miles.

[image]

When both the clouds and atmosphere is placed around it at 0, 0, 92.96 million miles.

[image]

Please note that I did attempt to remove the sun from render and I lit it with a lamp and there was no change.

Comment: Have you adjusted the [clipping](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/23787/30849)?

Comment: That a little bit too far where blender can hold the precision of the render equation. Did you change the unit scale for it? It might works when the value is in a reasonable size

Comment: The issue has to do with the z buffer on very large distances. If the clip distance is too large you loose the ability to distinguish from objects that are too close to each other (like all of the layers for the clouds and atmosphere. Reduce the clipping distance so that it encompasses only the object being rendered and not the whole universe.

Comment: Read: [what are the implications of a very large scene](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82986/what-are-the-implications-of-a-very-large-scene-scale-wise-relative-to-the-def/83013#83013) and [weird shading effects when rendering at long distances](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21647/weird-shading-effects-when-rendering-at-long-distance/21759#21759) and [advice for creating scene with very large dimensions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23787/need-advice-for-creating-a-simple-scene-with-very-large-dimensions)

Comment: the clipping is set to a few billion miles and can view everything. I have tried drastically lowering and raising to no effect. As for the scaling, the sun and earth are 1, while earths clouds is 1.005, and earths atmosphere is 1.015.

Comment: Sorry not clear for it. I mean the **properties panel > Scene > Units > Unit Scale**.

Comment: The units scale is set to 1.0, how can i just add my .blend file to the thread if people are interested?

Comment: Upload here would be a good idea: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Again. The amount of numbers available for the depth buffer can be quite large, but is a limited number, it cannot deal with values that are different by large magnitudes. If the clipping is set to billions of kilometers, any 3d engine (not just blender) will have a hard time differentiating objects that are just a few meters or even a few kilometers away.

Comment: @cegaton I was wondering the problem may caused by the floating point issue with large value in ray calculation. It might help calculation by setting those true value to a small one by unit scale. Not sure if I am right..

Comment: @Hikariztw good point.

Comment: In any case the issue, in my opinon, is that the scene is at resolution and scale where extremely large and small distances cannot be accurately calculated. I would suggest just baking the textures into a single material and a single mesh to render at long distances, and use a more detailed set if meshes and materials for close ups, or have some form of adaptive resolution (LOD), which I know nothing about.