# Is it possible to change the far clip distance more than max value?

Tags: 3d-view

The problem is, that my object disappears, when its far away. That happens because the clipping doesn't allow greater values that 100m unless I change the unit presets and therefore scale the whole object. That would be not so good, because I would have to rescale it than after exporting to get it right in unity. If I could just adjust the clipping distance a bit more that would be cool. Is there maybe a way to move the clipping spectrum from 10um-100m to something like 10cm-1km without changeing the whole scaling.[image: my house starts clipping there]

PS: I wanted to add the tag 'clipping'; can someone create that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 3D view, Object mode. Press N then change the Start and End of clip to whatever you want.[image]

Comment: Your answer didn't really tell it to me, but still thanks, I just tried typing something and i can just not adjust the value with the mouse, but I can type super high values.

Answer (score 0):

When using the mouse to adjust the clipping distance there is a limit. When clicking and then typing a number there is no limit. So for bigger numbers just type, what is needed. (for smaller it's the same)

Comment: Just be careful that you don't set a clip range that is much larger than your scene. You might run into precision issues like Z-fighting. If the start and end clip distance are set to a very wide range, 3D engines (blender included) will fail to differentiate faces that are very close together (here's an [example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21759/1853).
)